# how to put float: right; Font Awesome icon on same line?

Tags: html, css

In the code below after applying float: right; on i tag the Font Awesome icon arrow goes to the right but not on same line.

I want the arrow should be on same line like attached image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<style type="text/css">

.content {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

div {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

i {
    float: right;
    color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}    

</style>
</head>
   <body>

   <a class="content" href="/United Arab Emrits">
       <div>National and world news with background material, activities, discussion starters and teaching guides.</div>
       <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>
   </a>

   </body>
</html>
```

[image: In the code above the output should be like attached image.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML ought to be like this and we can add `line-height` to the icon class:

```
 <a class="content" href="/United Arab Emrits">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right my-icon"></i>
   <div>National and world news with background material, activities, discussion starters and teaching guides.
   </div>
</a>
```

and add this style to your CSS:

```
.my-icon{
  line-height:40px;
}
```

Working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/L4pkc07e/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have closed your div and defined `<i></i>` outside the div which is creating new line for your image. close your div after defining the image. 
sample.

```
<div> <i></i> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the css as following:

```
.content {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
div {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    margin-right: 40px;
}

i {
    float: right;
    color: green;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top:10px;
}
```

Please check the jsfiddle link for your solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/wv1mnyqk/